# Uncrustify config options for block after return formatting

Tags: code-formatting, objective-c++, uncrustify

What config settings can I make of use of to make `uncrustify` format like the the expected output for ObjC++ code.

#### Input:

```
SomeObject *buildObject()
{
  return
    BuildObject(^(CKComponent *) {
    [[[Object alloc]
      initWithLogger:[Logger new]
      async:YES]
     copy];
  });
}
```

#### ✅Expected Output:

```
SomeObject *buildObject()
{
  return
    BuildObject(^(CKComponent *) {
      [[[Object alloc]
        initWithLogger:[Logger new]
        async:YES]
       copy];
    });
}
```

#### ❌Actual Output:

```
SomeObject *buildObject()
{
  return
    BuildObject(^(CKComponent *) {
    [[[Object alloc]
      initWithLogger:[Logger new]
      async:YES]
     copy];
  });
}
```

#### Config options used:

> indent_off_after_return_new = true
>   indent_single_after_return = false
>   indent_oc_block = false
>   indent_continue = 0
>   use_indent_continue_only_once = true